# http delete in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS and still learning. I have this code below as delete. But I am having an error

```
$scope.deleteEmployee = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    var _ID = e.PersonId;
    var _url = '../Home/Delete?ID';
    $http.delete(_url, _ID).then(function (response) {
        alert(response.data.msg);
        GetList();
    });
}
```

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Home/Delete/?ID:1`

**Controller.cs Code**

```
  public JsonResult Delete(int ID)
    {
        try
        {
            var _data = db.People.Where(a => a.PersonId == ID).SingleOrDefault();
            db.People.Remove(_data);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { msg = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Json(new { msg = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems your API is not working as expected (Route is not defined as you are using). Check your API is working first using some tools like postman (if you are using WebAPI 2 - set Attribute routing  [Route("Home/delete")] or try to remove "/Delete" from Angular code

Comment: @SanthoshS, hello. i'm still new to angularJS.. but upon creating my project. I Uncheck the Web API from the list.. BTW my project is in MVC